# How to select either rows or columns in a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

By default, in a JTable, if you select a cell, that cell's entire row is selected.  I would like to keep this functionality.

However, the buttons in the header (above each column) do nothing by default.  I want to be able to click one of them and have that entire column be highlighted (and I dont want to get rid of the ability to select entire rows by doing this)

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Found another example at https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-allow-row-or-column-selection-in-jtable/ :

"To allow a row selection or a column selection or both row and column selection in JTable component we can turn it on and off by calling the JTable‘s **setRowSelectionAllowed()** and JTable‘s **setColumnSelectionAllowed()** methods.

Both of these method accept a **boolean** value indicating whether the selection is allowed or not allowed. **Setting both of them to true allow us to select rows and columns** from JTable."

```
package org.kodejava.example.swing;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import java.awt.*;

public class TableAllowColumnSelection extends JPanel {
public TableAllowColumnSelection() {
    initializePanel();
}

private void initializePanel() {
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 150));

    JTable table = new JTable(new PremiereLeagueTableModel());
    // sets to false to disallow row selection in the table
    // model.
    table.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);

    // Sets to true to allow column selection in the table
    // model.
    table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);

    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
    this.add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public static void showFrame() {
    JPanel panel = new TableAllowColumnSelection();
    panel.setOpaque(true);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("JTable Column Selection");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setContentPane(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            TableAllowColumnSelection.showFrame();
        }
    });
}

class PremiereLeagueTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    // TableModel's column names
    private String[] columnNames = {
        "TEAM", "P", "W", "D", "L", "GS", "GA", "GD", "PTS"
    };

    // TableModel's data
    private Object[][] data = {
        { "Liverpool", 3, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0, 7, 9 },
        { "Tottenham", 3, 3, 0, 0, 8, 2, 6, 9 },
        { "Chelsea", 3, 3, 0, 0, 8, 3, 5, 9 },
        { "Watford", 3, 3, 0, 0, 7, 2, 5, 9 },
        { "Manchester City", 3, 2, 1, 0, 9, 2, 7, 7 }
    };

    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return data[rowIndex][columnIndex];
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: There is also a demo picture at the site at the bottom after the original writers code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this only works for column selection, because of the line     table.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);  If I set it to true, then they will both be true and I will only be able to select individual cells.  I want it to be impossible to select individual cells, I only want the user to be able to select rows (by selecting a cell in that row) or columns (by selecting the header)

Comment: Updated answer.